# Spring profiles set multiple default profiles in web.xml

Tags: java, spring, web.xml

I have looked in the documentation of Spring profiles.
They clearly say that multiple active profiles are possible.
This you could [find back here](http://spring.io/blog/2011/02/11/spring-framework-3-1-m1-released/).

Does this also means multiple default profiles are possible?

You can register your default profile in your `web.xml` by this way :

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>spring.profiles.default</param-name>
    <param-value>HOSTED</param-value>
</context-param>
```

But how can I register in the `web.xml` multiple default profiles (or multiple active)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add them as a comma separated list:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>spring.profiles.default</param-name>
    <param-value>HOSTED, ANOTHER_DEFAULT_PROFILE</param-value>
</context-param>
```